# How can I merge two files using PIG script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two files. And I want to merge it sequentially. How can I do so using Pig/PigLatin script?

```
f1.csv
1,aa
1,aa
1,ab
1,ac
2,bd
2,bd
2,bd
4,ab
4,bc

f2.csv
1,xxx
1,xxy
1,xyx
1,yxx
1,xyy
1,yyx
2,pqr
2,pq
2,pqrs
2,pqs
3,def
```

And the output i need is

```
1,aa,1,xxy
1,aa,1,xyx
1,ab,1,yxx
1,ac,1,xyy
2,bd,2,pqr
2,bd,2,pq
2,bd,2,pqrs
```

Can anyone help me which join should be used and how to get this?

Comment: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#join-inner - i think the example pretty much covers it, but your expected output will have every combination of first field pairings - you seem to be asking for something a little different, or is your expected output incomplete? (there will be 24 pairings for the first field value of 1)

Comment: I think this is going to require a custom input format

Comment: Please explain more.  What happened to `1,xxx`, among others? What is your (mental) algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

1) LOAD each file.

2) Then UNION them together

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#UNION

3) STORE the new unioned alias.

P.S. You can SET DEFAULT_PARALLEL 1; to make sure you only output one file.